# What is the purpose of object i and r in dojo

Tags: javascript, caching, dojo

I was testing my code and I noticed dojo is complaining about missing "i" object. I wasn't sure about it so I start debugging. I noticed dojo is using i, or r obj in several places and it was expecting my obj to contain the format such as Object {i: Object, r: Object}
Have you heard of something like this before?
If so what is the general purpose of using item i and r?

I appreciate any tips or suggestions.
Thx in advance.

Comment: which dojo source files you are using? If you are using the minified versions than all names will be minified (i.e shortened) and if will be difficult for you to debug. So all the variable names will appear a,b..i,j..i1,j1.. and so on. You need to download the dojo source version instead of the minified version for you to debug the code.

Comment: thx for the comment. For example one of the places is QueryReadStore getIdentity method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the comparision of the **getidentity** method in **memory.js** file

In the minified verstion the code is as

```
getIdentity:function(_6){
return _6[this.idProperty];
}
```

where as in the source version the code is as

```
getIdentity: function(object){
        // summary:
        //      Returns an object's identity
        // object: Object
        //      The object to get the identity from
        // returns: Number
        return object[this.idProperty];
    },
```

If you see above the code variable naming is quite different also the comments have been stripped from the source version, even though the functionality of the code remains the same.

Comment: This is not the case with the `QueryReadStore`. It really used the `n` and `i` properties in the source code of it :p

Comment: Link to source code: https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/data/QueryReadStore.js#L495

Comment: Thx fokes for all the comments